# It should return true but it says false and I dont know why

Tags: kotlin

I am programming something and I was testing something with **assertEquals** and I am pretty sure that it should return true but the test says it is false. The value im testing is "hasEnded"
I will show you the relevant code to my case:

*Note:* Everything I deleted was tested already and kept the only important code to my case "hopefully"

```
class Schwimmen(
    var hasEnded: Boolean = false
)
```

```
fun nextTurn() {
    val game = rootService.currentGame
    game.hasEnded= checkForEnd()
```

```
private fun checkForEnd(): Boolean {
    val game = rootService.currentGame
    return (game.cards.size < 3 && game.playerPassCounter >= game.players.size) ||
            (game.activePlayer == game.endGamePlayer)
}
```

```
fun testNextTurn(){
    testRootService.schwimmenService.startSchwimmen(players)
    testRootService.currentGame?.cards?.clear()
    testRootService.currentGame?.playerPassCounter = 5

    assertEquals(true, testRootService.currentGame?.hasEnded)
}
```

The Test failed and I got: AssertionFailedError: expected: "true" but was: "false"

Comment: Are you sure it isn't null?

Comment: I wouldn't get false from program if it was null, and no there is nothing related to hasEnded implemented as null

Comment: If `currentGame` definitely shouldn't be null for this test, you might want to use the `!!` non-null assertion so the rest of the test is clearer (since it smart-casts to non-null). And so if it ever *is* null, it's clearer what part of the test is failing (one of the preconditions, not the logic that's actually under test). You could always do an `assertNotNull` before the `!!` if you wanted, but that might be better as its own test

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
I forgot to call "nextTurn()" to run checkForEnd() in test

```
@Test
fun testNextTurn(){
    testRootService.schwimmenService.startSchwimmen(players)
    testRootService.currentGame?.cards?.clear()
    testRootService.currentGame?.playerPassCounter = 5
    **testRootService.schwimmenService.nextTurn()**
    assertEquals(true, testRootService.currentGame?.hasEnded)
}
```